# Pigeonhole-like property on permutations of a finite cyclic group

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, pigeonhole-principle

Let $n\geq 1$. Question : is it true that for any permutation $\sigma$ of
$\frac{\mathbb Z}{2n{\mathbb Z}}$, there are two indices $i,j$ such that
$1\leq i < j \leq 2n$ and

$$
\sigma(j)-j = \sigma(i)-i
$$
I call such a pair $(i,j)$ good for $\sigma$.

My thoughts :

1. With the help of a computer, I have checked that the answer is yes for $n\leq 5$.
2. If $\sigma$ is the particular permutation defined by

$$
\sigma(k)=\begin{cases}2k-1,& \textrm{if }\ k\leq n, \\ 2(k-n)& \textrm{if }\ k >n.\end{cases}
$$

Then there is only good pair, namely $(1,2n)$.

Comment: See Exercise 7 **(a)** in http://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~grinberg/t/18f/mt3s.pdf (page 46), if I got your question correctly.

Comment: @darijgrinberg You got it perfectly correctly indeed, thanks. If you wish, you can write a sketch of the answer and I'll accept it, or perhaps I'll delete this question.

Comment: Of topic, how you made that picture on page 16? @darijgrinberg

Comment: @Aqua: tikz. I believe I have stolen the relevant code from tex.SE and modified it somewhat. See the \newcommand\kstaircasepath[6] in https://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~grinberg/t/18f/mt3s.tex .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See Exercise 7 (a) in [my Fall 2018 Math 5707 midterm #3 solutions](https://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/%7Egrinberg/t/18f/mt3s.pdf) (page 46). Here is the relevant part:

> **Exercise.** Let $n$ be an even positive integer.
>
> For each $\sigma\in S_{n}$, prove that there exist two
> distinct elements $i$ and $j$ of $\left[  n \right]  $ such that
> $\sigma\left(  i \right)  - i \equiv\sigma\left(  j \right)  - j \mod n$.

(Here, I am using the notation $\left[n\right]$ for the $n$-element set $\left\{1,2,\ldots,n\right\}$, and the notation $S_n$ for the group of permutations of this set.)

*Solution.* Let $\sigma\in S_{n}$. Thus, $\sigma$ is a bijection from
$\left[  n\right]  $ to $\left[  n\right]  $. Hence, we can substitute $i$ for
$\sigma\left(  i\right)  $ in the sum $\sum_{i\in\left[  n\right]  }
\sigma\left(  i\right)  $. We thus obtain
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i\in\left[  n\right]  }\sigma\left(  i\right)  =\sum_{i\in\left[
n\right]  }i.
\label{sol.perm.roundtable.a.sum} \tag{1}
\end{equation}

For each integer $z$, we let $z\%n$ denote the remainder of $z$ when divided
by $n$.

Assume (for the sake of contradiction) that the $n$ numbers
\begin{equation}
\left(  \sigma\left(  1\right)  -1\right)  \%n,\qquad\left(  \sigma\left(
2\right)  -2\right)  \%n,\qquad\ldots,\qquad\left(  \sigma\left(  n\right)
-n\right)  \%n
\label{sol.perm.roundtable.a.nums} \tag{2}
\end{equation}
are distinct. Thus, the map
\begin{align}
\left[  n\right]  \rightarrow\left\{  0,1,\ldots,n-1\right\}  ,\qquad
i\mapsto\left(  \sigma\left(  i\right)  -i\right)  \%n
\end{align}
(this map is well-defined, because for each $i\in\left[  n\right]  $, the remainder $\left(  \sigma\left(  i\right)  -i\right)  \%n$ belongs to $\left\{
0,1,\ldots,n-1\right\}  $) is injective. Therefore, by the
Pigeonhole Principle for Injections, this map must also be bijective (since it
is an injective map between two finite sets of the same size). In other words,
it is a bijection. Hence, we can substitute $\left(  \sigma\left(  i\right)
-i\right)  \%n$ for $j$ in the sum $\sum_{j\in\left\{  0,1,\ldots,n-1\right\}
}j$. We thus find
\begin{align}
\sum_{j\in\left\{  0,1,\ldots,n-1\right\}  }j=\sum_{i\in\left[  n\right]
}\underbrace{\left(  \left(  \sigma\left(  i\right)  -i\right)  \%n\right)
}_{\substack{\equiv\sigma\left(  i\right)  -i\operatorname{mod}
n\\\text{(because }z\%n\equiv z\operatorname{mod}n\\\text{for each integer
}z\text{)}}}\equiv\sum_{i\in\left[  n\right]  }\left(  \sigma\left(  i\right)
-i\right)  =\sum_{i\in\left[  n\right]  }\sigma\left(  i\right)  -\sum
_{i\in\left[  n\right]  }i=0\operatorname{mod}n
\end{align}
(by \eqref{sol.perm.roundtable.a.sum}). In view of
\begin{align*}
\sum_{j\in\left\{  0,1,\ldots,n-1\right\}  }j  &  =0+1+\cdots+\left(
n-1\right)  =\dfrac{\left(  n-1\right)  \left(  \left(  n-1\right)  +1\right)
}{2}\qquad\left(  \text{by Little Gauss}\right) \\
&  =\dfrac{\left(  n-1\right)  n}{2},
\end{align*}
this rewrites as $\dfrac{\left(  n-1\right)  n}{2}\equiv0\operatorname{mod}n$.
In other words, $n\mid\dfrac{\left(  n-1\right)  n}{2}$. In other words,
$\dfrac{\left(  n-1\right)  n}{2}/n$ is an integer.

But $\dfrac{\left(  n-1\right)  n}{2}/n=\dfrac{n-1}{2}$ is not an integer,
because $n-1$ is odd (since $n$ is even). This contradicts the fact that
$\dfrac{\left(  n-1\right)  n}{2}/n$ is an integer.

This contradiction proves that our assumption was false. Hence, the $n$
numbers listed in \eqref{sol.perm.roundtable.a.nums} are **not** all
distinct. In other words, there exist two distinct elements $i$ and $j$ of
$\left[  n\right]  $ such that $\left(  \sigma\left(  i\right)  -i\right)
\%n=\left(  \sigma\left(  j\right)  -j\right)  \%n$. These $i$ and $j$ must
then satisfy
\begin{align*}
\sigma\left(  i\right)  -i  &  \equiv\left(  \sigma\left(  i\right)
-i\right)  \%n\qquad\left(  \text{since }z\equiv z\%n\operatorname{mod}n\text{
for each integer }z\right) \\
&  =\left(  \sigma\left(  j\right)  -j\right)  \%n\\
&  \equiv\sigma\left(  j\right)  -j\operatorname{mod}n\qquad\left(
\text{since }z\%n\equiv z\operatorname{mod}n\text{ for each integer }z\right)
.
\end{align*}
Thus, we have shown that there exist two distinct elements $i$ and $j$ of
$\left[  n\right]  $ such that $\sigma\left(  i\right)  -i\equiv\sigma\left(
j\right)  -j\mod n$. This solves the exercise. $\blacksquare$

(See also [Permuting elements of a set around a circle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/281094/permuting-elements-of-a-set-around-a-circle/281468#281468) for a similar but more advanced variant of this problem.)